# Setting limit for checked checkboxes

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm having somewhat of a problem an application that I'm working on. So, I want to set a limit of 3 checkboxes that can be checked, but I'm not sure how can I do it. Here are a few pictures of what it should look like...

[image: before]
[image: after]

I'm quite new at this, so I tried doing this but couldn't work...
Here are my codes

```
if (checkedsec1 >= 3) {
    banana.setEnabled(false);
}

banana.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

        if (banana.isChecked()) {
            totalcash += 1.80;
            tc.setText(String.format("%1$,.2f", totalcash));
            checkedsec1++;
        } else {
            totalcash -= 1.80;
            tc.setText(String.format("%1$,.2f", totalcash));
            checkedsec1--;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var counter : Int = 0
val maxLimit = 3
banana.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                         boolean isChecked) {
            if(isChecked){
                counter++;
                 if(counter == maxLimit){
                    buttonView.setChecked(false);
                 }
            }else{
                 counter--;
            }

      }
});
```

Comment: If i apply this, i would have to actually click on the checkbox to disable it. I am wondering how i could automatically disable the other checkboxes once i have reached the limit.

Comment: For the app i am working on, i have 5 checkboxes and i can only choose 3 out of the 5. If i were to use "counter == maxLimit", in my case, "checkedsec1 ==  3", it will only uncheck my 3rd choice and still allow the "totalcash" to add up and allow me to move on to the 4th and 5th choice. I would like that once i hit 3 checkboxes, the other 2 gets disabled, and if i were to repick my 3rd choice, the disabled other 2  including my 3rd choice would be enabled again. Sorry if this sounds confusing btw.